# How can I use map to return a modified dictionary based on conditions in one line of code?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

Hello I am supposed to write a function `CustomOp(d)` that takes a dict d and is used in the following way:

```
dict(map(CustomOp(d), d.items()))
```

The function is supposed to help modify the dicts values based on the following conditions:

1. If the dict only contains integers: double each value.
2. If it only contains strings: reverse each string.
3. If the dict contains other types or multiple different types: return unmodified dict

In addition the function `CustomOp(d)` is supposed to be written in one line of code (disregarding the head obv)

---

Here is what I have been able to do so far. Proceeding with caution is advised!

```
def UseOp(d):
    return dict(map(CustomOp(d), d.items()))
```

```
def CustomOp(d):
    return lambda t:tuple([t[0],t[1]*2]) if all(type(v)==int for v in d.values()) else lambda t:tuple([t[0],t[1][::-1]]) if all(type(v)==str for v in d.values()) else lambda t:t
```

---

It works only when the Dict only contains only integers otherwise I get:

> TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence

I have no idea how to get this line to work and how it is possible to make it any shorter and after a considerable amount of time I have decided to give up and ask you guys.

Comment: Are you able to write `CustomOp` with multiple lines of code? I would try that first and only then try to condense it to a single line.

Comment: And are you able to do 1. 2. and 3. individually? I would also try that first.

Comment: running your code with individual lines works fine, still looking at the one-line version.

Comment: frankly i have not tried that before might be a good idea next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to fix the problem:

```
    def CustomOp(d):
        return (lambda t:tuple([t[0],t[1]*2])) if all(type(v)==int for v in d.values()) else (lambda t:tuple([t[0],t[1][::-1]])) if all(type(v)==str for v in d.values()) else lambda t:t
```

The issue is how things are grouped between the `if`-`else` statements and the `lambda` statements.
By enclosing your `lambda` statements in parentheses, the function works as expected.  Your logic was good. You just didn't account for operator precedence/grouping...

Comment: Wow thanks I would have never figured that out thanks a lot. I wish I could like your post but i dont have the reputation it seems. I am still left with the question if this is possible with less than 170 chars in that damn line though

Comment: @NoCodeNoBlunder - I think you should still be able to select the Answer as the best answer.

Comment: You may be able to achieve the 170 chars if you combine the type checking with something like all(type(v) in (int,str) for...)

Comment: @NoCodeNoBlunder - Great. If you post the 170 char Q, I can help you with that, too. Or at least try. :)